# Scaling AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I have a queue with a lot go messages coming from different sources. I also have lambda to process the messages in this queue. The point is I can read only up to 10 messages per one SQS request.  Since we have time limit for lambda it means I can make not more than 10 invocations in my case per one lambda function run. 
How can I "tell" lambda to run multiple function instances at a time to process more messages per time from the queue?

Comment: How is the lambda being triggered? Is it on a timer or is it event-driven?

Comment: It is being triggered on timer currently because amazon doesn't support triggering lambda on SQS message.

Comment: Queue processing is tricky in Lambda, but not impossible. Assuming your code has at least one loop structure, one trick is to check the time remaining in the lambda function at the beginning of each loop iteration. If there is not enough time remaining (say 10 seconds) then manually invoke the Lambda function again and exit. AWS Batch is another architecture to consider as it has no time limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, given your current setup there's not really a good way to optimize it without significant overhead. If you want more than one lambda to be triggered by your timer, you could have multiple timers or a faster timer. However, you would need a large amount of overhead to ensure it is working as expected. There are a couple of solutions you could consider to make this more efficient:

1. Use Kinesis Streams
2. Send messages through SNS instead of buffering in a SQS Queue and process them real-time
3. Move lambda code into a docker container and create an AWS service out of it that can act as a multiprocessor for SQS (i.e. have 5 instances of the container running at a time with scale-up/down triggers)

I would highly recommend the SNS option if you can avoid using SQS since it has the least overhead. Under the hood of every AWS integration method for a lambda lies an SNS endpoint anyway. It's how the service is set up. SNS integration will bring up an instance of the lambda every time a message is sent and scale with your usage instead of you needing to manage your scaling and distribution. That will cause unnecessary headaches.

As for running a lambda on a timer, it is bad practice to use a service that is set up to be event driven on a timer. Personally, when I develop for AWS, all of my event driven functionality is Lambda and all of my time driven functionality is written into docker containers then run on ECS. Running lambda on a timer is something that was developed after the fact due to customers requesting it, not something the service was intitially intended for.

Comment: Sending from SNS to Lamda is not a guarnteed execution. Check this forum. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=204539

Comment: Ok then, which approach would better meet my requirements?
I have a database hosted in RDS, tis database generates events (tasks). I want to process those tasks by lambda. Which approach should I use to deliver new tasks from RDS database to lambda?

Comment: @Kannaiyan That blog post mentions nothing wrt the performance of SNS -> Lambda integration, only that the retry behavior is limited. In my 2 years of running services on AWS I have never seen a failure in my SNS -> Lambda integration and the only thing I could think of that might cause that is if Lambda goes down for some reason

Comment: I don't like the idea of using SNS, because it is publisher-subscriber model. It means all the subscribers receive the same message. And I have to take care  about the restriction - taking care of having only one subscriber. At the same time Kinesis looks like an overhead. Wouldn't it be better to use DynamoDB streams?

Comment: @AndreiTarutin One subscriber means one Lambda ARN which encapsulates any number of invocations of that lambda. Is there another service ingesting messages?

Comment: @asdf SNS does not comes with lot of other mechanisms that Kinesis offer, like replay messages, failure handling. On the other hand DynamoDB streams does not behave differently than Kinesis, it just adds DynamoDB into the equation.

Comment: @asdf not now, but it might be in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best fit for you would be using Kinesis streams instead of SQS.

[AWS documentation on concurrent Lambda execution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html)

Comment: Why not DynamoDB streams?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Kinesis where all these are automated.

You can set the batch size to your desired size and it will get delivered in batches. If you want to run them in parallel, you can either create multiple streams and assign it to the same Lambda, it will create instance for every stream.

Comment: I don't want to take care about splitting messages into multiple streams. I just want lambda to be run with multiple instances.

Comment: There is nothing out of the box for your needs, unless you manage the parallel computing with another lambda for now.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, a solution may be to change your lambda to do the following:

1. Receive the messages from SQS
2. If more than zero were received,
   use the Lambda API to self-invoke. This will cause a parallel
   execution of another instance of the Lambda to run while the current
   invocation is processing the messages in step 3. You *must* use the `Event` invocation type for this to work..
3. Process the
   messages.

This is a form of recursion with the base case being "no more messages in the queue".  Each invocation of your lambda will process one batch, with batches being processed in parallel so long as more messages can be pulled from the queue. Once the queue is empty, no more invocations will be created until the next time the lambda is triggered by the timer.

This isn't a *great* solution, but it will work effectively for you and shouldn't be a significant change to implement since it doesn't require you to change architecture at all.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html